# ImportError: No module named 'zope' for cryptoassets.django while running the initialize database command

Tags: python, django, bitcoin

Okay, Im trying to use cryptoassets.django here. Iv got some help from Mikko about the python version being an issue(I was using 2.7.x, cryptoassets uses 3.4.x). I just solved by doing this

```
$virtualenv -p python3 venv
```

I also reinstalled Django because manage.py was pulling up error, probably because it was overwriting the bin/activate.. files.

With that out of the way. I installed the cryptoassets.django app

```
$pip3 install cryptoassets.django
```

Wonderfull. I set  it up like the tutorial on bitbucket for the [cryptoassets django intergration](https://bitbucket.org/miohtama/cryptoassets.django).

The problem comes in when i try to initialize the cryptoasset database with

```
$python manage.py cryptoassets_initialize_database
```

I get an Import error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'zope'
```

Here is the Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/caleb/Desktop/bitkoin/lib/python3.4/site-   packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in   execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/home/caleb/Desktop/bitkoin/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 343, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/caleb/Desktop/bitkoin/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 190, in fetch_command
  klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/caleb/Desktop/bitkoin/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 40, in load_command_class
module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/home/caleb/Desktop/bitkoin/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in   _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/caleb/Desktop/bitkoin/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cryptoassets/django/management/commands/cryptoassets_initialize_database.py", line 5, in <module>
from cryptoassets.core.service.main import Service
 File "/home/caleb/Desktop/bitkoin/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cryptoassets/core/service/main.py", line 25, in <module>
from ..configure import Configurator
  File "/home/caleb/Desktop/bitkoin/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cryptoassets/core/configure.py", line 13, in <module>
from zope.dottedname.resolve import resolve
ImportError: No module named 'zope'
```

What could be the issue now.

Comment: The only thing clear from the traceback is that there is a problem with loading service.main module from cryptoassets app. You need to give more details: do you run django globally, without using pip? have you tried to reinstall cryptoassets app? are you sure that cryptoassets itself works as expected, installed it somewhere else?

Comment: i run django in virtualenv so i use pip quite often and i have tried reinstalling it so many times in different apps, i keep getting the same error. I know about a couple of other apps that run cryptoassets so, i am guessing it works as expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cryptoassets is Python 3.4+ only and you are trying to run it on Python 2.

Comment: That makes alot of sense now. I kind of deduced as much. Thanks

Comment: If you need help with installation please edit the question and add exact commands which you are using to install and run the package.

Comment: Do i need to install zope or should it work regardless?

Comment: Cool. You need to install all the requirements as specified in `requirements.txt` here http://cryptoassetscore.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#installing-the-release-version

Comment: It solved that pretty well.Thanks.I know this is getting old but..another one: `ImportError: No module named 'cryptoassets.core.backend.sochainwalletnotify'
` .FYI the database initialized and created it tables. The error above is from when i try to get the helper service up.

Comment: @E11: Wonderful! If you run any issues with Cryptoassets please open issue here https://bitbucket.org/miohtama/cryptoassets/issues?status=new&status=open

Comment: It's hard to figure out from your comment what could be wrong. I suggest you open a new question with more information and drop a link to it here. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, i cant post another question for a day so i will try make it as explicit as possible. Now , I have run the database and helper service commands with no problems but is there any other config i need to sync my blockio account testnet because the default wallet notify pulls up an error...**ImportError: No module named 'cryptoassets.core.backend.sochainwalletnotify'
** so i am using the websocket config instead.

Comment: I voted up some comments, so you should get some reputation.

Comment: Sounds like it is an installation error. That module should be available always or it is mistyped somewhere. I should need to see the source tree, how virtual environment is set up, what commands you us to launch, etc. to tell better.

Comment: Hey, I tracked down the problem. The config in the database section was using sqlite3 instead of sqlite. Its all good now..